# How to configure WebSphere administration console for two simultaneous logins?

Tags: websphere-8, zos

I have two WebSphere 8.0 environments set up; test and production. When I connect to the WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console of the test or production environment I do this via `sub.domain.com:port/ibm/console`... The difference between accessing the production or test environment console is in the port number of the URL.

My problem is that if I, for example, log into the production environment and I'm already logged into the test environment I can do that, but when I want to switch back to the test console and continue working there I'm prompted to login again.

I think that the problem lies with the cookies and the session. So is there a way to tweak this? I didn't find anything useful in the documentation or on the web... Any reading recommendations? If only a hint, into the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the cookies gets confused, since the only difference is the port.

I use either of the following tricks (depends on the environment I'm working with):

- Use different browser for each environment (e.g. FF for prod, and IE for dev)
- Access one environment via hostname, other via IP
- Create few virtual host names (aliases) in your local etc/hosts file and access different environment via different hostname.